# Cuando hago un gráfico con ggplot me aparecen rayas a lo largo del gráfico y no me reporta ningún error en la sintaxis

Tags: r, ggplot

[[image: Deberia aparecer boxplot por año pero aparecen rayas a lo largo del gráfico de ggplot][1]]

No hay error en sintaxis en el código pero al parecer hay un error de base[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu codigo debe ir como texto!

Comment: Esas rayas que ves, seguramente son diminutos boxplots, hay algo en tu gráfica que está mal definido. ¿Que es la variable X? Y por cierto sigue las recomendaciones que te han dado, y en cuanto a tu pregunta: el código siempre como texto y un ejemplo mínimo para reproducir el problema. Suerte.